# How will i able to select the data using laravel5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi im new to laravel im using 5.2 and im still learning 
My problem is how will i able to select the data from which i queried in the database ?

Here's my view code below

```
 <label>Target Country: </label>
                <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control" onchange="getCityList(this.value, 'city')">
                    <option>Select Country :</option>
                    @foreach($countries as  $country)
                        <option value="{{$country->id}} " ({{$countryId }} == {{$countryId}}) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''  >{{$country->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
```

And my code to get the data on the database

```
 $countryId     = \App\Person::find($this->request->session()->get('newPersonId'))->companies()->get(['country_id'])[0]->country_id;
```

I want the result to be this way:

```
<option value="{{$country->id}} " selected='selected; >{{$country->name}}</option>
```

any help is muchly appreciated! TIA

Comment: What do you mean, "Select the data"? Put them in checkboxes and have some kind of result with only the data belonging to the checked boxes?

Comment: no just the data to be selected something like this <option value="1 " selected='selected; >test</option>

Comment: @phpdev Where did you get the `companies()` function from?

Comment: its ok i already solve this thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<option value="{{ $country->id }}" {{ $countryId == $country->id ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}}>{{ $country->name }}</option>
```